# Installed plugin fails to load, looks like web pack doesn't see it ReferenceError: HtmlWebpackPlugin is not defined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, webpack, plugins, web-config

In essense, I am tring to set react with Webpack

used this command:

`npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin`

here is webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    },
    port: 3000,
  }

};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cdn_one_react_webpack_diff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello, React</h1>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel">


    </script>
</body>
```

I tried reconfiguring the folder from scratch,

I did not use any CDN' here.
Researched the whole internet an there are not so many tips on how to act in this situantion, so I simply stuck, since
the code of the plugin installation in written but it doesn't work

Of course, I used this command:

`npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin`

Comment: If you install the `html-webpack-plugin` successfully, why the `devDependencies` does not contain it?